# Firebase getCurrentUser return weird data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I run some test to my authentication code, call register activity and successfully register using email password , put data in database in the progress and finally intent to my next activity and finish my register Activity..

the problem raise when i close and reopen my app,  where is main activity run and execute the auth listener to get the current User

```
 // [START auth_state_listener]
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                final User NewUser = new User();
                NewUser.setName(user.getDisplayName().toString());  //ERROR HERE , ATTEMPT INVOKE NULL OBJECT
                NewUser.setAddress("");
                ...
```

This code is my first auth listener for every user/provider, and running well if i reopen my app after login via FB or Google. the problem only for user i logged in/registered using email password.  i tried to debug , the user is not null but it contains weird key like zzDBY, zzbYH , etc

So the error message about invoking null object on this line `NewUser.setName(user.getDisplayName().toString());`

what is the cause and how to fix this ?  how do i get my auth data  ?

here is my register code :

```
private void createAccount(String email, String password, String password2, String name, String dob, String gender) {
    Log.d("REGISTER USER", "createAccount:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }

    showProgressDialog();

    // [START create_user_with_email]


    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(UserRegistration.this, "Failed - EMAIL ALREADY REGISTERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                            } else {
                                //do nothing
                            }

                            hideProgressDialog();


                            // ...
                        }
                    });
```

after register process is success, the auth listener in my registerActivity do the rest :

```
// [START auth_state_listener]
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

                User Newuser = new User(name,email,"-","-",dobText,gender,10,"-",services,transactions,0);

                // new user node would be /users/$userid/
                String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();  //generate Primary Key

               // mDatabase.child("Users").child(userId).child("username").setValue(name);

                //pushing user to 'users' node using the userId
                mDatabase.child("Users").child(userId).setValue(Newuser);

                // send to next activity
                Intent home = new Intent(UserRegistration.this , HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(home);
                Log.d(TAG, "Register:onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                finish();
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "Register:onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };
    // [END auth_state_listener]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a crash because `FirebaseUser` doesn't have any displayName set yet so method `getDisplayName()` returns `null` and you then are calling another method `toString()` on a null object reference (btw calling `toString()` is redundant here because method `getDisplayName()` already returns a `String`).

Make a check before using it.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getDisplayName())){
   //user has displayname so you can use it
}
```

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38115889/3185707) how to update user's displayName after creating profile. This is needed most of the times when user signed up with email and password. When a user is signed up with socials displayName will be taken from socials' profiles then.

Comment: so the firebase auth keep information for each profile ? , i remember yesterday i try to login via FB, logout, then log again using google, but the information from getCurrentUser not changed. (e.g : display name  is my fb name, photoUrl also from my fb , not my Google photo),did i make mistake or its from firebase default ?

Comment: When user logins with socials with the same email firebase merge those accounts (this is normal behaviour for most of websites as well) so user can login in it's account using different types of signin. The same happens when user creates account with email and password and then signs in using socials. So it wasn't your mistake, when you login with facebook for the first time your firebase user info was taken from facebook profile, then if you want to change it you need to do it yourself.

Comment: but i just try create email password (xxx@gmail.com) , success, check console OK, then i logOut and log in via FB (same email) , but i got error authenticate failed..  , why firebase don't merge it ?

Comment: I recently tried again, from create email-password , logout and then login using google sign in (same email) and it worked well. the console change its provider from email to google logo now, so only from email to fb is not working.. _com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address._

Comment: make sure you setup signin with facebook properly in firebase console (app ID, app Secret, redirect Uri), see more here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login#before_you_begin

Comment: thanks, i better open a new question to avoid wrong topic issue